# Sorting Fields within a record

Tags: database, file, gnu, recordset

I have a very simple `test.rec` file with a small descriptor and 2 records.

```
%rec: Test
%mandatory: Foo
%mandatory: Bar

Foo: yes
Bar: yes

Bar: no
Foo: no
```

recfix is perfectly fine with this, however I am not. I would like every record to have its Foo field at 0 and its Bar field at 1.

I am aware of the `%sort` descriptor, its semantics and that it will only affect print order, not file storage order (unless explicitly invoking `recfix --sort test.rec`).
`recsel test.rec` will print:

```
Foo: yes
Bar: yes

Bar: no
Foo: no
```

This is not what I want. I want:

```
Foo: yes
Bar: yes

Foo: no
Bar: no
```

Ideally i would like to declare my desired field order such that `recfix` can rearrange miss-sorted records in my **file** and **not** just print them out using some variation of `recfmt`.

Of course i could just write a script using any other unix-utility to do this for me, but Id be suprised if this wasnt possible with recutils itself.